# Redis with 3 node cluster is keep on switching master

Tags: redis, memcached, database-administration, redis-sentinel

My redis cluster keep on switching the master. Below are the logs.

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 20:51:57.673 # +switch-master mymaster IP1 6379 IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 20:51:57.673 * +slave slave IP2:6379 IP2 6379 @ mymaster IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 20:51:57.673 * +slave slave IP1:6379 IP1 6379 @ mymaster IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 20:59:33.956 # +sdown slave IP1:6379 IP1 6379 @ mymaster IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:00:39.950 # -sdown slave IP1:6379 IP1 6379 @ mymaster IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:44.989 # +new-epoch 3741

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:44.991 # +vote-for-leader 3df3b3dbeb6fabb0bc24da5adaa41209d1be9997 3741

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:45.083 # +sdown master mymaster IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:45.166 # +odown master mymaster IP3 6379 #quorum 3/2

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:45.166 # Next failover delay: I will not start a failover before Thu Aug 26 21:17:21 2021

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:46.074 # +config-update-from sentinel 3df3b3dbeb6fabb0bc24da5adaa41209d1be9997 IP2 26379 @ mymaster IP3 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:46.074 # +switch-master mymaster IP3 6379 IP1 6379

4580:X 26 Aug 2021 21:16:46.075 * +slave slave IP2:6379 IP2 6379 @ mymaster IP1 6379

Comment: Any solution for this? We are facing the same issue. In sentinel log there is no error seen.